# Manipulate datagridView and view by criteria

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to manipulate my dataGridView to view people only who have failed.It should display the unsactisfactory mark and a Pass if he/she passed the particular test.

> I'm getting and DataGridView Default Error Dialog

```
 try
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
     {
          if ((int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value >= 50)
             dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "Pass";

          else if ((int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value >= 50)
                  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "Pass";

          else if ((int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value >= 50)
                  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "Pass";

          else if ((int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value >= 50)
                  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "Pass";
    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: instead of changing/manipulating data in datagridview you should change it in datatable or the datasource of the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //if (e.ColumnIndex >= 1 && e.ColumnIndex <= 4)
        if ((int)e.Value >= 50)
            e.Value = "Pass";
}
```